# Why do the exposed filters in my view return to previous values after I change them?

Tags: views

I have a catalogue list organised as a table with 4 exposed filter criteria set up. The page can be found [here](http://www.mml.co.za/catalogue). An export of the view can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9480491/catalogue_view_export.txt).

When a user runs the filter it works fine, but if they change the value of one of the filters and run it again, the search returns the results of the previous search and reverts to the previous value of the filter.

I know that if I enable a 'reset' button and the user resets the search that this works, but it is rather strange that if the user only wishes to change one of the filter criteria and keep the others the same that they cannot. They have to reenter all the criteria again.

Is there a configuration option that I am missing somewhere? I am running Views 7.x-3.0-rc1

---

Update: I have just noticed that even with the reset button that things do not work as they should.

If I hit 'reset' the query string at the end of the url is removed and the filter text boxes become blank. If I then add new criteria and hit 'apply' the querystring reflects the new filters, but the filter text boxes and the results reflect the original filter values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the reason for the failure of the filter to update was that I had caching enabled on the view. Once I turned this off the exposed filters worked correctly.

Comment: I had a similar case. I replicated a particular view's exposed filter to use as a block on main page, via a custom module. When the submit redirected user to the principal views page, the query string was stuck at the original value used at front page. Cache was disabled, but I had to disable "Remember..."  and ajax as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can select under each exposed filter, if Views should remember the selection or not. Remembering the last selected value will be stored as a session variable and persist until the user logs out etc.

Comment: I don't think that is it. My exposed filters have that checkbox unflagged.